# Intialize Vue data with the result of an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, promise

I need to initialize a Vue component's data with the result of an AJAX call. I tried the following:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    supplierCount: 0
  }
},

created: function () {
  axios.get("/supplier/list").then(response => {    
    this.supplierCount = response.data.length;
  });
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work, because the template can access the data before the AJAX handler updates `supplierCount`.

What's the correct way to initialize the data with the result of an asynchronous call? For example, if I return a promise (instead of an object) from `data`, will Vue wait until the promise is rejected/resolved before exposing the data to the template?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can force your component to initialize only after the ajax call, but you **can** configure it to be hidden before the ajax data is loaded, either by hiding it with css (using `v-show`) or by simply preventing its rendering (using `v-if`).

For example, you can add a property `hasLoaded` to your component, and bind either `v-show` or `v-if` to it, like this:

On your js:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    supplierCount: 0,
    hasLoaded: false
  }
},

created: function () {
  axios.get("/supplier/list").then(response => {    
    this.supplierCount = response.data.length;
    this.hasLoaded = true;
  });
}
```

On your template:

```
<!-- The top element is your root element, and you should always render it, so the v-show is appended to the immediate child -->

<div>
    <div v-show="hasLoaded">
        <!-- the rest of your template goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Render your template `html` conditionally.

That's the best way I believe - Nothing get added to DOM if condition fails.

```
 <div v-if="supplierCount">

</div>
```